# Indefinite Server Requests in Air for Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I am making an Android application using Flash CC and Air for Android. The application will run continuously (part of the time in the background) on multiple devices and will need to keep asking a server about a certain operation and receiving a yes/no answer.

What would be the best approach to do this? If I use a Timer, it seems to have "up to a maximum of 24.86 days" limitation.

Also, what would be a good approach not to waste too much of the battery as the application will continuously run in the background, never turned off.

Answer (score 1):

The limitation on the `Timer` class is due to the maximum value of an signed, 32-bit integer. `Timer` stores its current value as an `int`, in ms since the start. 24.86 days in ms happens to be 2147904000, or close to the max value of a signed, 32-bit integer (2147483647). The difference between the two is likely made up due to rounding in the true max value of the `Timer` class.

Anyway, your best bet is to reset the timer every single time. So:

```
var t:Timer = new Timer( delay, 1 );
t.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler );
t.start();

function timerCompleteHandler( e:TimerEvent ):void {
    // do stuff here
    t.reset(); // resets timer to 0
    t.start(); // restarts timer
}
```

In terms of battery usage, that is a tricky question. I've never dealt with an app always running in the background before. I would definitely avoid having it do anything resource intensive. So things like changing any element of the GUI should be off-limits if the app is inactive/running in the background. Really, we need to know more about what you want to do in the background to determine how to help here. From what you have described here, it almost seems like you would be better off setting up push notifications than using a custom call to your server.

Comment: Your reply is very helpful. Regarding battery usage, things appear to be managed well by the OS itself. I created a 60 second timer, sending requests to the server and logging them. I left the app running all night. The log is very interesting: there are about 2 requests an hour most of the night, until 9:20 or so when requests started coming in every minute for about 20 minutes and then went back to twice an hour. I think Any.do or some other app activity around 9 must have caused this.

Comment: Keep in mind that AIR only runs at 4fps in the background. I'm not sure if that would affect your app at all, but it is worth noting.